# Load icon into UIImageView strategy in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uiimageview, icons

What is better, to size an svg image in Adobe Illustrator to the appropriate image sizes i.e. if icon is 40x40 then create a 40x40, 80x80, 120x120, and name them like sth.png, sth@2x.png, sth@3x.png, or just save png with 512x512 size, and use that one and let system to resize it?

What do you prefer, which one generates better resolution?

Answer (score 1):

In our experience, we have our designers export icon images for each size. This guarantees that we have control over the final look of the icon in every display case. They have a simple photoshop script that exports all appropriate icon sizes from the 1024x1024 master, then they check them for graininess and redo them where necessary.

It's a matter of preference, really. As I'm not a designer, my opinion may not matter much, but I usually can't tell the difference. ;)